# Integrate Facebook’s Account Kit with Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, parse-server

I'd like to integrate the new login framework from Facebook, Account Kit (which among others provides phone login), to my iOS app, which uses Parse.

I was able to integrate the framework successfully; i.e., I was able to complete the flow: user inputs his phone number -> gets an SMS with a code -> enter it and successfully get a token.

What I’m not sure is what do to next — how to follow up with the integration to Parse?

Other related questions which came to my mind are:
 1. Do I need also some Cloud code to deal with it?
 2. How do I check if the current user is a new or existing user?

I’d love for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only Cloud Code, I guess. You need to integrate [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-accountkit-auth) in your Parse Server.

**Another way**

If you can't do server stuffs, there is lazy, crappy and bad way to implement the integration. But this solves the problem.

The method is

Get the user's phone number after user has logged-in with phone number.

Develop an Algorithm that will generate password from the given phone number.

`NSString generatePassword(NSString phone)`

After the user has logged-in with accountkit, check if his phone number is already at Parse

If the user's phone number is not at Parse, `signUpInBackground(phonenumber, generatePassword(phonenumber), callback)`

Unless, `logInInBackgroud(phonenumber, generatePassword(phonenumber), callback)`

Hope this would help :)

Comment: Got you! And if I’m now in process of moving to Parse Server, but currently has a live app that still uses Parse.com — so the only way to go for the last 2 months before Parse shutdown is option #2?

Comment: Yes, I guess so